# How to select odd/even elements by class, that are not siblings?

Tags: html, css, dom

How to select odd/even elements with a particular class, randomly positioned in the DOM, using CSS? They are not siblings, the only common thing they share is the class name. I tried `nth-child`, `odd`, `nth-of-type` pseudo classes but I could not achieve this.

Comment: you cannot do this ..

Comment: only possible with js, or if the elements and their parents are not random

Comment: Alright, understood. I don't use jQuery so I will probably just make a new class and apply it. Thanks.